# What happens when you train one specific muscle (ex, biceps), and you don't eat enough protein?

Tags: exercise, workout, nutrition, training, protein

Does the body break other muscles (ex, legs, chest, etc) to get the needed protein to repair the microdamage ?

This is very interesting question that has always been on my head.

Comment: I have voted your question as being off topic. If you read through the help section, you will note "What if" questions are not allowed. You can edit your question to try and improve it.

Comment: Reference dietary intakes are around 61g of protein for someone on a 2000 calorie intake OP, let that simmer in your brain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any protein intake, that protein will be used to repair and over-compensate the microdamaged muscle tissue. More protein will make this response stronger.

If you literally don't have any protein intake, you will have many different medical issues, one of them being that you are unable to repair this damage, meaning you will be catabolic.

Comment: Would it be possible to reduce catabolism in one muscle alone by training that one muscle alone, though, so its size relative to other muscles increases?

Comment: Afaik, you won't break down your other muscles to build up the single one. When muscle is broken down due to calorie restriction, it is used for energy. If you have enough protein and exercise there, you will build up that muscle though, if you don't exercise the other ones, they will become smaller eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one day a week then increasing your protein the following day will leave some extra protein for yesterday underfed muscle to be replenished and repaired efficiently. 
It is nothing grot worry about as far as you are hitting your weekly goal your body has a way if evenly distributing protein accordingly. The beauty of our body is the mechanics within.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, if you don't eat enough protein it's likely that the body will get protein from other less used muscles, also if you eat enough calories but not enough protein you can still improve your strength but you won't improve your size much(you could even get fatter).
Strength improvements are much faster with a bigger protein intake though.